# Drawing ends up all black

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to resize an image via HTML canvas, but when I display it, it displays all black.

**My code**

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageData;

    window.setTimeout(function() {

        var maxSize = 200;

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = maxSize;
        canvas.height = maxSize;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img.src, 0, 0, maxSize, maxSize);

        dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        alert(dataurl);
    }, 1000);
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what it is I'm doing incorrectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is imageData an url or data URI?

Comment: If it's an URL, is it from the same host as the webpage?

Comment: @AlvinLindstam DATA_URL from the same page...It's coming from a user's phone. I think the issue is that I'm trying to draw it before it renders

Comment: Yes, probably. Checked the load event of the first image element?

Comment: Too little info. Guesses:  (1) You use "imageData" but `context.getImageData` is not a valid image .src. (2) Converting from image sources with alpha to "image/jpeg" (which doesn't contain alpha) causes part of the .jpg to be black -- but not the whole .jpg. (3) You must wait for the second image (profileImage) to load before drawing it (use profileImage.onload). Not waiting causes an empty space, not necessarily a black space. (4) "ctx.drawImage" might be tainting the canvas because of a cross-origin security error. Local images (same phone) are often declared cross-origin.

Comment: @markE imageData is a base64 string from an image I get from the phone (cordova app), so I assume that might not be the correct way to do it. I updated my post with different code

Comment: Use .onload for both img and profileImage. Start debugging! Any errors in the F12 debugging console? Add img to the DOM -- does it appear? If yes, you have a valid img. Add profileImage to the DOM -- does it appear? If yes, you have a valid profileImage.

Comment: My 2 cents worth... `ctx.drawImage(img.src,...`  should be `ctx.drawImage(img,...` as `img.src` is a string not an image and would be throwing an error at that line thus not drawing anything at all giving you a black canvas.

Comment: @Blindman67 that was the issue! Thanks!